# Edits required to be six or more characters

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

I recently tried to correct an error in an answer but failed because I ran into the requirement that edits to posts must to be six or more characters. All I wanted to do was to add a missing ",". That was the only change that was needed. Is there a work-around for this? Even better, can it be eliminated?

Comment: There are [at least 107 questions on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=edit+6+characters) about this. It's a network-wide feature. [Here's a relevant one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149771/legitimate-edits-of-less-than-6-characters).

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. I do not feel comfortable with MSO, but surely I have to do more efforts there to learn these things.

Answer (score 2):

At [2000 rep](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit), you get full editing privileges for questions and answers.

You have 3886 rep.

Are you sure you were logged in?